# Is The Binding of Isaac well playable with keyboard?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac, keyboard

I have been interested in playing **The Binding of Isaac** since quite a while, but I wonder if playing via keyboard might be a disadvantage in-game. It looks kind of Twin-Stick like...

Comment: As long as your keyboard doesn't ghost keys: yes, it's well playable.

Comment: What counts as, "well-playable"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's playable with keyboard.

Moreover, on [Steam store page](http://store.steampowered.com/app/113200/The_Binding_of_Isaac/) this game doesn't even have 'Full controller support' tag. So there is no advantage in playing with controller.